# Selecting most recent news article in a collection with Linq to Sql

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, linq-to-sql

I have a bunch of news articles and I want to select the most recent one using Linq to Sql. I have an MVC action method like so

```
[ChildActionOnly]
public ActionResult LatestNews()
{
    var article = mhndb.NewsArticles.Single();

    return PartialView("LatestNews", article);
}
```

I would like to know the syntax for selecting the most recent item in the NewsArticles collection using Linq. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest option is to use OrderByDescending and then `FirstOrDefault()`:

```
var article = mhndb.NewsArticles.OrderByDescending(a => a.PostedTime)
                                .FirstOrDefault();
```

(If you use `First`, it will throw an exception if there are no entries. With `FirstOrDefault`, it will return null.)

If you want to use a query expression, it will look something like this:

```
var article = (from a in mhndb.NewsArticles
               orderby a.PostedTime descending
               select a).FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use something like

```
mhndb.NewsArticles.OrderBy(a => a.publishDate).Last()
```

Comment: Using `Single` will blow up if there's more than one entry. And using OrderBy instead of OrderByDescending will give the *earliest* entry rather than the most recent one.